# How do I get Lumen to use DB::transaction?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm using Lumen with a SQLite DB. I've tried everything I can think of to use `DB::transaction` in Lumen, but to no avail.  I consistently get errors like this:

`ReflectionException: /vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php line 779`

I've tried putting `use DB;` at the top of the class.  I've tried `use`ing the facade.  Nothing seems to work.

Simple example of trying to use it:

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($attributes, $service) {
   $this->person = $this->person->create([]);
   // do some other stuff
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to run a `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Yep. Tried `composer dump-autoload` after each change.

Comment: Have you un-commented this line?

https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/master/bootstrap/app.php#L22.

Mine works like a charm:

`\DB::transaction(function ($connection) { dd($connection); });`

Comment: Yup, I've I've uncommented that line and the Eloquent line. Perhaps it has to do more with the fact I'm using a SQLite database then?

Comment: In what context would you be using the facade? A controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've struggled to use transactions using `DB::transaction` in Lumen myself. A workaround that I ended up using is to just resolve the database using the global function `app()` instead of the facade and then use the transaction on that like so:

```
app('db')->transaction(function() {
    // DB work
});
```

If there are a lot of these you can also cache the result of calling `app('db')` in a variable for reuse. It will behave just like the static calls on `DB`.